# Cant access state name inside directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

For some reason $state.current.name is always blank when I try to access it from a directive controller. Does the directive load before state evaluation? If so, is there a work around for this? I need to show the correct navigation based on the state in a SPA

For example in my view, I have: `<navigation></navigation>`

My directive:

```
angular.module('app')
        .directive('navigation', function($state){
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                controller: function() {
                    alert($state.current.name);
                }
            }
         });
```

My routes:

```
angular.module('app')
        .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
            $stateProvider
                    .state('home', {
                        url: '/home',
                        views: {
                            "title": {
                                template: "<title>Home</title>"
                            },
                            "body": {
                                templateUrl: 'app/components/home/homeView.html',
                            },
                            "navigation" : {
                                templateUrl: 'app/shared/navigation/homeNavBarView.html'
                            }
                        }

                    })
        });
```

The way i have it set up is that i create the module separately, then i setup routing in a separate file, and the directive is also in a separate file. Then they are loaded in an index file in order. Not sure if this has anything to do with it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Does your controller also have to have $state as a parameter?
Just a guess as everything looks solid to me:

```
controller: function($state) {
    alert($state.current.name);
}
```

Comment: scope is injected inside the directive wrapper

Comment: it doesnt really make a difference

Comment: I'll keep working on it. Strange because what you have looks correct to me.

Comment: The way i have it set up is that i create the module separately, then i setup routing in a separate file, and the directive is also in a separate file. Then they are loaded in an index file in order. Not sure if this has anything to do with it

Comment: @NuGnojMik However the Angular framework's way is DI. I am working on the same problem, there may be a way $watch or $observe the $state of ui-router. I do not know [this topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/4Gcn7bwjkS0) how to resolve it.

Answer (score -2):

Use $state.`$current object` instead of `$state.current`

Comment: doesnt make a difference